# Saving a JPanel in to png file

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a payslip generator. I already got my GUI to generate the payslip on a separate `JPanel`. When I click "Save as PNG" button it is currently saving the Jpanel as a png file inside the project folder. But I want it to be able to specify both file path and the file name when saving. Here is what I have done so far.

```
public static BufferedImage getScreenShot(Component component) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    component.paint(image.getGraphics());
    return image;
}

public void saveScreenShot(Component component, String fname) throws Exception {

    BufferedImage img = getScreenShot(component);
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(fname));
}
private void SaveAsPNGButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

    try {
        saveScreenShot(PaySlip, "My panel Image.png");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

I want it to be something like the code below. This one I'm using to save  searched results from a `Jtable` to a text file.

```
 private void Export2TextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    try {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int option = fc.showSaveDialog(SearchEmployeeGUI.this);
        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
                String path = fc.getSelectedFile().getParentFile().getPath();

                int len = filename.length();
                String ext = "";
                String file = "";

                if (len > 4) {
                    ext = filename.substring(len - 4, len);
                }

                if (ext.equals(".txt")) {
                    file = path + "\\" + filename;
                } else {
                    file = path + "\\" + filename + ".txt";
                }
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write("Employee ID       First Name      Last Name       Gender      Contact No      Email       Date of Join        Designation     Basic Salary");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                bw.newLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < EmployeeTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < EmployeeTable.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                        bw.write(EmployeeTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, j) + "    ");
                    }
                    bw.newLine();

                }
                bw.close();
                fw.close();
                int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to open the exported file?", "Successfully exported!", option);
                if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
                        dt.open(new File(file));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

In here I can specify the path and also the file name. I want same thing for `"Save as png"` button. but I have no idea how to do that. can somebody please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

```
                String suggesteddir = ".";
            String EXTENSION = ".png";
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(suggesteddir);
            JFrame choose = new JFrame();
            choose.setTitle("Save To ...");
             int status = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(choose);
            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            {

                try 
                {
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    String newfile = selectedFile.getCanonicalPath();
                    if (!newfile.endsWith(EXTENSION)) {
                        newfile=newfile + EXTENSION;
                    }

                    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(newfile)); //write img to file

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
```